# Is there a way to remove units from a calc function in CSS

Tags: css, calc

I'm currently using the following rule:

```
margin-left: calc(((100vw - 624px) / 144) * 5);
```

At 1200px viewport width this gives a value of 20px. What I actually *want*, however, is to get a result of 20%. Ideally that would mean changing the multiplication factor of '5' from an integer to '5%'. But in order to do that I need to remove the units from the rest of the calculation, so that calc would be processing `4 * 5%` rather than `4px * 5`.

In SASS I could divide by 1px, but in calc you can only divide by a number, not a united value.

Is there a way to remove units from part of a calc function?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. Also even looking into sass and less, browser support plus math calculation limitations are a hurdle in getting the result you want. I think you may have to use jQuery for this calculation.

Comment: I don't think there is a way.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`strip-unit`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/strip-unit-function/) function for SASS and other CSS preprocessors, but there's no comparable function in CSS3.